# What do crowns above steps mean?

Tags: pikmin-bloom

After waking over 3000 steps, the counter has a crown over it.  Is there something special about this?  Are there other step amounts with different rewards?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crown indicates the day when you have walked the largest number of steps in the view.

Here's two separate weeks from my log, in each case, the day with most steps receives the crown.

[image]
[image]